# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox Timeout

Tags: perl, firefox, mechanize, www-mechanize

How do I properly use a timeout when I attempt to make `->get(URL)` requests with `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`?

`my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(timeout => 10);` does not seem to work

Comment: [You're not the first one to wonder about this.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22311475/176646) Unfortunately, it seems like this isn't supported by W::M::F, so you may have to implement a timeout yourself with [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to simulate this, at least to a good extent.

You can turn off synchronization for `get`, in which case the call should return immediately. Then poll every `$sleep_time` until timeout, with some test of whether the page completed. The sleep allows all those other good pages to complete, so set `$sleep_time` as appropriate.

```
my $timeout = 10; 
my $sleep_time = 1;

my $page = get($url, synchronize => 0); 

for (1..$timeout) {
    # Test some page property that will confirm that it loaded
    last if $page->title eq $expected_title;
    sleep $sleep_time;
}
```

There is the issue of how exactly to confirm each page, but this should provide a working timeout.

Comment: I see that this is an older post, but an idea for a simple timeout could be useful.